# how to i import/use ctx for a python discord bot?

Tags: python, discord

im making a python discord bot in replit and i cant get ctx to work
i tried `import ctx` and i just get an error message like *AttributeError: module 'ctx' has no attribute 'message'* heres my code:

```
import discord
import ctx
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith(""):
        print(message.content)
        guild = ctx.message.guild
        await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the ctx parameter, you're supposed to use the commands extension for discord.py. In the `on_message` event you can use the `message` parameter "as ctx parameter".

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        if message.content.startswith(""):
            print(message.content)
            guild = message.guild
            await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use the `ctx` library to access the `message` variable's guild property. Try the following:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith(""):
        print(message.content)
        guild = message.guild
        await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')
```